# preg_grep returning whole string instead of part

Tags: php, regex

the following code is run

```
$mysqlquery = "SELECT `description` FROM `table`";

$sqlresourceid = mysql_query($mysqlquery);
$subject = mysql_fetch_row($sqlresourceid);
$regexisbn = '/(97(8|9))?\d{9}(\d|X)/i';

$pattern = '/.*/i';

$matches  = preg_grep ($regexisbn, $subject);

var_dump($matches);
```

however this returns the following

```
ISBN10: 0470945176 by Paul D. Kimmel Publisher: John Wiley & Sons Copyright year: © 2011
```

I just wanted it to return the ISBN 0470945176 , how come this is happening?

Comment: I strongly suggest you have two different regexes: One to match ISBN-10s (`/\d{9}[\dX]/`) and one to match ISBN-13s (`/97[89]\d{10}/`).  ISBN-13s cannot end with an X.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's what [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/manual/function.preg-grep.php) does: it filters an input array, removing the non-matching entries. Then matching entries are left untouched.

You want to try `preg_match` or `preg_replace`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get only the matching part of the regexp, try this:

```
$str = 'ISBN10: 0470945176 by Paul D. Kimmel Publisher: John Wiley & Sons Copyright year: © 2011';
preg_match('/(?P<my_isbn>(97(8|9))?\d{9}(\d|X))/i', $str, $matches);
echo 'ISBN: <b>' . $matches['my_isbn'] . '</b>';
```

Your result would be:

ISBN: **0470945176**